# ARIA Landmarks not working in textarea / input

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

When I put `role="main"` in the `textarea` element:

```
<textarea role="main" aria-label="text area"></textarea>
```

The screen reader (JAWS) not read for me this region when I click on 'r' or 'q' as it should.

When I set the landmarks attributes to the parent div - it's working.

Isn't landmarks supported in inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARIA roles and aria-* attributes can be applied to HTML elements as long as they don't conflict with the HTML element's strong native semantics. This is by design and the reason is to prevent authors to convey wrong/misleading information to assistive technologies.

[The WAI-ARIA section of HTML 5.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#wai-aria) gives the strong native semantics of the `textarea` element as follows:

> `textbox` role, with the `aria-multiline` property set to "true", and the `aria-readonly` property set to "true" if the element has a `readonly` attribute

Applying `role="main"` on a `textarea` would conflict with textbox role, therefore it is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work in any way.
A landmark (or region) is designed to be accessible to screen readers, so a user would know where it begins, where it ends, and he/she could easily move to the region.
A textarea, like other input, is a form field. When you land onto a form field, you enter so-called form mode. This means that you can type text, and the **r** key would actually type the "r" character on screen, and not move to the next region.
So roles like main, region and so on are meaningless and useless on other elements than div-like elements and paragraphs.

Comment: Correct, I know. But when I'm not focused on the textarea and I like to go to this area because it is my main  context? like chat textarea. In this example, when the user 'traveling' on the page and wants to go back to the main context - there the 'role="main' would be useful...

Comment: Then set your `main` role to the parent div. And you can also programmatically set focus to the textarea using `$("textarea").focus();`